# I am getting this error where It says "No known class method for selector 'getLottoNumber'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am getting this error with my code : No known class method for selector 'getLottoNumber'.

```
- (IBAction)generateButton:(id)sender {

LottoDataController *lottoDataController = [[LottoDataController alloc] init];

int firstNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];//I get the error here
int secondNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];//and here
int thirdNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];//and here
int fourthNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];//and here
int fifthNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];//and here
int sixthNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];//and here

[self.numView1 showLottoNumber:firstNumber];//Then I get this error: No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'showLottoNumber:'.
[self.numView2 showLottoNumber:secondNumber];
[self.numView3 showLottoNimber:thirdNumber];
[self.numView4 showLottoNumber:fourthNumber];
[self.numView5 showLottoNumber:fifthNumber];
[self.numView6 showLottoNumber:sixthNumber];

}


@end
```

lottoDataController.h:

```
@interface LottoDataController : NSObject

- (int)getLottoNumber;

@end
```

lottoDataController.m:

```
@implementation LottoDataController

-(NSMutableArray *)generateRandomUniqueNumber;

{
    NSMutableArray *unqArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int randNum;
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 6)

    {
        randNum = arc4random_uniform(40.0);
        if (![unqArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]])
        {
            [unqArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randNum]];
            counter++;
        }

    }
    return unqArray;
}


@end
```

That is my project and I don't know what is going on.
Anything wrong with it??
Now I need To Waste Some Space Because My Post is Mostly Code.
..................................................................................

Comment: Warning says all. No known class method for selector

Comment: Have you declared/implemented this method anywhere?

Comment: Show `LottoDataController`

Comment: Thanks. This Problem is Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot read a property from a `class object`, you have to read it using `instance object`.
Change

```
 LottoDataController *lottoDataController = [[LottoDataController alloc] init];

 int firstNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];
```

To

```
LottoDataController *lottoDataController = [[LottoDataController alloc] init];

int firstNumber = [lottoDataController getLottoNumber];
```

Comment: @MatthewHarris your numView1 is an `UIImageView`?

Comment: And yes, my numView1 is an     UIImageView

Comment: @MatthewHarris ... where i your `showLottoNimber` method? `UIImageView` do not have any inbuilt method like this. Have you created any subclass of `ImageView`?

Comment: @MatthewHarris where is your `showLottoNimber` method?

Comment: In my numberView class

Answer (score 0):

Well, with …

```
int firstNumber = [LottoDataController getLottoNumber];
```

… you try to read a property from a *class object* instead of the created instance object.

BTW: You should read a tutorial about Objective-C.